mysql table locks failing tomcat connection pooling and http
I need to execute the below commands though mysql scheduler to refresh the full-text indexes in a table -
ALTER TABLE some_table DROP INDEX full_text;
ALTER TABLE some_table ADD FULLTEXT INDEX full_text (description) VISIBLE;

But this locks down the table which does not quite fails the tomcat 9.0 connection pooling but the entire http requests fails across all the web projects deployed. I can see in the tomcat logs the background queries to the connection pool works just fine.
I have to restart the tomcat server after which everything works fine.
the connection pool string -
<Resource name="myDatasource" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
maxTotal="100" maxIdle="30" maxWaitMillis="10000" username="username" password="password" 
driverClassName="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?useOldAliasMetadataBehavior=true"/>

I have another simple mysql connection below which never fails although -
if(con1 == null || con1.isClosed()) {
      Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
      con1=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb","username","password");
}


Have you read about how to optimize a fulltext index in stages? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html#fulltext-optimize

well thankyou @BillKarwin but any kind of locking to the tables even for 1-2 seconds is breaking down tomcat http

do you have any connection checking happening on a regular interval within tomcat or your JDBC connection?

@Vihar nope but as I wrote in the question, the connection pool is active and gets accessed from java classes. Http service is broken.

@PradyutBhattacharya You should give more information: how it is failed, what happened?

Any ALTER TABLE statement needs a table lock, at least briefly. That's just how they work. By the way, it is not typically required to drop and recreate the fulltext index frequently. Perhaps once in a while, but not often. Why are you doing that?

@BillKarwin well i'm doing it once in a day to delete around 500 duplicate entries and recreate indexes. I was doing it earlier once every hour. Now i have to check at a specified time of the day if tomcat http has failed or not. But i guess with optimize it might not fail.
